# caching images & data with phonegap locally

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cordova, slim

I have a phonegap app using slim with ajax front.  When I listing a certain page, I would like to cache the data and then just use that till user refreshes or sends a trigger for new data.

so far I have this for caching json data:
//caches the JSON data into localstorage

```
try {
                                localStorage.setItem('cachedProducts', JSON.stringify(data));
                                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cachedProducts'));
                                var bar = localStorage.getItem('cachedProducts');
                                clog(bar);

                            } catch (e) {
                                clog("didn't work");
                            }
```

it works.  but i have no idea how to save images or how to trigger the server for new data.  thank you.

Comment: very poorly formatted question. Please be clear about what you want.

Comment: I wanna be able to modify my ajax call to either get things locally or remotely, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to save small number of image then you can convert it in to base64 string and store it in to local storage. You can covert images in to base64 string using canvas. If user tries to refresh the content then you connect to the server and cache the latest content.

Comment: ok thank you, but sounds good, how would I reach & display the content though? I have everything setup,  but this part
$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: ""
              data: data,
              dataType: "json",
              cache: false,

I would like to customize this part so ajax either gets data locally or gets from server.

Comment: k you can check whether local storage have data or not if local storage does not have data then request it from server below is the code if(localStorage.getItem('cachedProducts')) { //get the data from local storage } else { //request from server using ajex call}

Comment: cool, thank you.  I was trying to see if I can have a switchable ajax call for remote and local, but I guess, that's ridic :)

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do with switchable ajax call for remote and local? I didn't understand that part. Are you trying to get the data from local storage using ajax call?

Comment: k fine. Image caching you can do it easily by canvas.